# Quarkus - swagger-ui - smallrye configuration

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, quarkus, smallrye

Some configurations regarding swagger-ui and smallrye openapi are defined in build time likes :

- quarkus.smallrye-openapi.oidc-open-id-connect-url
- quarkus.swagger-ui.oauth-client-secret
- quarkus.swagger-ui.oauth-client-id
- quarkus.smallrye-openapi.security-scheme-name
- quarkus.swagger-ui.oauth2-redirect-url

I guess it would be preferable to define them at runtime because my opend-id-connect-url depends on the infrastructure and may be changed depending on the runtime context (local run using docker compose, prod run using k8s).
Moreover I would not want to put the secret at build time in my production application.properties (because value could be stored in a Vault and retrieved at run time).

Would it be possible to be laxist by defining theses kind of configurations dynamically at run time ? (I may not be exaustive in this list of configuration).

Regards,

Damien

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by using smallrye jwt instead of oidc.
I've followed this nice blog to do it https://www.itix.fr/fr/blog/secure-quarkus-api-with-keycloak/